# let s be a set with N elements and A1,...,A101 be 101 (possibly not disjoint) subsets of S

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

So the question I'm having problem with is the following: let s be a set with N elements and A1,...,A101 be 101 (possibly not disjoint)  subsets of  S with the following 5 properties:

1. each elements of S belongs to at least one subset of Ai ∈ {A1,...,A101},
2. each susbset Ai∈ {A1,...,A101} contains exactly 1000 elements of S,
3. the intersection of any pair {Ai,Aj}of distinct subsets of {A1,...,A101} contains exactly 200 elements,
4. the intersectin of any 3 distinct subsets {Ai,Aj,AK} of PA1,...,A101} contains exactly 6 elements
5. the intersection of any 4 or more distinct subsets of {A1,...,A101} empty

Using the inclusion/exclusion principle, compute N and cardinality of S.

I really don't know how to approach this problem.. Step by step would be very much appreciated thank you

Comment: [How to format mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  By your first condition we have
$$S=A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_{101}\ .$$
The inclusion/exclusion formula for $101$ sets is
$$\eqalign{
  N=|S|
  &=|A_1|+|A_2|+\cdots+|A_{101}|\cr
  &\qquad {}-|A_1\cap A_2|-\cdots\cr
  &\qquad {}+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|+\cdots\cr
  &\qquad {}-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|+\cdots\cr
  &\qquad {}+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4\cap A_5|+\cdots\cr
  &\qquad {}-\cdots\ .\cr}$$
Now the first line on the right hand side contains $101$ terms, each equal to $1000$, for a total of $101000$.  See if you can do a similar calculation

- for the second line;
- for the third line;
- and then see what happens for the fourth and all subsequent lines.

Good luck!

Comment: I regret that your answer didn't get more upvotes, because when I saw it I thought you had given exactly the right amount of hint. I just wanted to let you know I had liked it.